# My function returns an empty array, while the sort function works

Tags: python

My function works perfectly if I write

```
array = sort(array)
```

but when I just use the function on my array

```
sort(array)
```

the return is an empty array. This is probably a stupid mistake but I just can't find it. I return the res in the function?

```
def sort(array):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        minimum = array[0]
        for j in range(len(array)):
            if array[j] < minimum:
                minimum = array[j]
        array.remove(minimum)
        res.append(minimum)
    return res


array = [9, 1, 5, 7, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 0] 
sort(array) => array returns empty here
print(array)
```

Comment: You should include an [mcve].

Comment: Post all data here as text. Posting text as an image just needlessly complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the result, you need to copy its elements into the original list. So replace:

```
return res
```

with:

```
array[:] = res
```

Assigning to a slice inserts the list into that portion of the target list. The slice `[:]` refers to the entire list.

Comment: oke nice this works and what does array[:] exactly do? I just found on google it looks on every index number of the array so in this case he replaces all the values with the values in the res ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the statement

```
array.remove(minimum)
```

which in loop removes next and next element from the `array`, so finally it will remain empty. It is a side effect of your function.

So, if you use only

```
sort(array)
```

the return value is *not used* and the whole effect is in *clearing* the `array`.

On the other side, if you use

```
array = sort(array)
```

you replace the original value of the `array` with the *return value* of your function, which is value of your local variable `ret` in its definition.